# Don't want authentication after reverting back from other server to my spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on a POC (Spring boot application) where I am authenticating the user using the custom login form and my home page gets displayed.

then I am calling an URL from my JSP which is a different server(let's say another server with another spring boot application) URL. Where I performing some operation and revert back to my POC application.

now the problem is when I revert/redirect back to my application from other server, my application again ask for credentials even though I am logged in.

please suggest me what should do to log in again without prompt to my application.

for simplicity

My POC URL: `http://localhost:8084/POC/home` this is home page URL & it shows `index.jsp`

from `index.jsp` I am calling `http://localhost:8083/api/v1/net-calculate` which displays the calculation page and perform the calculation. once done it redirects back to my POC application by calling `http://localhost:8084/POC/calStatus` URL.

And here is the problem, when `http://localhost:8084/POC/calStatus`called my POC application prompt login page and after login I am able to see calculation status.

Controller method

```
@GetMapping(path = "/net-calculate")
public String calculate(PayLoad payLoad, Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    String status = calculate(payLoad);

    model.addAttribute("payload", payLoad);
    model.addAttribute("status", status);

    return "status";
}
```

Status JSP which get called after calculation done

```
<form action="${payload.callBckUrl}" name="form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="${status}">
    <input type="hidden" name="reqType" value="${payload.reqType}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.form.submit();
    </script>
</form>`
```

`payload.callBckUrl` is nothing but `http://localhost:8084/POC/calStatus`

Comment: Can you share the code how you are calling the `net-calculate` page? Is it `forward`? Also, share code how you are redirecting back to `calStatus`? Is it `sendRedirect`? I see a lot of things here which will cause a session loss.

Comment: calling net-calculate by form submit `<form action="http://localhost:8083/api/v1/net-calculate" method="get"> </form>`

Comment: and calStatus is also called using form submit `<form action="${payload.callBckUrl}" name="payform" method="post"> <script type="text/javascript">
   document.payform.submit();
  </script>
 </form>`

Comment: Your session Cookies are specific to a domain and you are losing that when going to a different domain.

Comment: Are you using a cookie or some other mechanism for tracking session?

Comment: no i am not using cookie

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197476/discussion-between-swapnil-patil-and-fiveelements).

Comment: Show your Spring Security configuration.

Comment: Are you think on use a SSO server to delegates the authentication process? i think it resolves your issue. Your apps will call SSO Server if request is not authenticated and will keep the user logged. Cas Server is a good product (it's a war can be deployed on any server)